# MP Android Chart, custom xAxis labels only on entries

Tags: java, android, graph, mpandroidchart, entry-point

***1)*** I'm practicing stuff with graphs in order to add that feture to my app, I want the upper labels ( the xAxis base ) to be shown only where entries occur.

I haven't found a suitable solution online yet, and currently it appears on every xAxis from first entry to last entry as in the picture below:

[image]

I want it to be without the one sI deleted, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

***2)*** and the second question I'm struggling with it is that I want to be able to draw for example in (x=5, y=7) and after it to draw at (x=1, y =3), but it wont let me add an entry with a smaller x that any other entry that already in the graph.

Comment: the people who downvote the question, care to say the reason?

Comment: The reason for the downvote, in my opinion, is that it does not make sense to show something in a chart that has no value and no label. maybe it shouldn't be there. However, I did not vote down cause you may have your reasons.

Comment: the labels should appear ONLY where there is entries, I Want to remove the ones that are above nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extend from ValueFormatter class.

for more detail take a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54763234/6751083)

You can pick your desired logic to make the label disappear with returning "".

for example:

```
public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
  if ((int)value <= 0) //your logic to evaluate correctness
      return "";  // make lable go away
  //...
}
```

UPDATE 2 (in Kotlin):
There is another overload for getFormattedValue which have a AxisBase parameter and you can use mEntryCount or mEntries.

```
override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
    if (axis?.mEntryCount!! <= 0)
        return ""
}
```

Comment: I extended it in order to get custom labels, but not sure how to get labels only on places that there are entries

Comment: I applied my logic, and now, it "does it" but not in a good way, it only put labels as the number of the entries but not in the right places(without spaces, it's like he is ignoring when I return "" )

Comment: I did a mistake with my logic, it works fine now, thank you !

Comment: do you have any solution for the second thing I asked/